# Why is my count variable not incrementing for each new instance of my class?

Tags: python, class

My code:

```
class Lobby(Definition):
    Lcount = 0
    def __init__(self):
        if Lobby.Lcount == 0:
            self.description = "test1"
        elif Lobby.Lcount > 0:
            self.description = "test2"
        else:
            print("\nHmmm something went wrong...\n")
        self.contents = ["Briefcase"]
        self.doors = {"n": "terminal", "w": "hallway"}
        Lobby.Lcount += 1
```

I want it to be where after an instance of the room has been created (i.e. you have visited it before), it will display a different description than it the original one. However, it keeps printing the same description. So what precisely am I doing wrong here?

edit: Here is what is in my definition class:

```
class Definition:

    def __init__(self):
        self.description = ""
        self.contents = []
        self.doors = {}

    def get_desc(self):
        print("{}".format(self.description))

    def get_direction(self):
        direction = input("Enter a direction or search the room: ").lower()
        search = True
        if direction == "q":
            return direction
        elif direction in self.doors:
            location = self.doors[direction]
            return location
        elif direction == "s":
            while search:
                action = input("\nYou search for some items... Press 1 to continue or 2 to quit.\n")
                if action == "1":
                    if len(location.contents) == 0:
                            print("\nYou find nothing of value in the room.\n")
                    else:
                        find = random.randrange(1, 3)
                        if find == 1:
                            found = random.randrange(len(location.contents))
                            item = location.contents.pop(found)
                            print("\nYou found a {}\n".format(item))
                            self.items.append(item)
                            self.check_items()
                        else:
                            print("\nNothing found yet\n")
                elif action == "2":
                    search = False
                    break
                else:
                    print("\nLocation reminder: ")
                    location.get_description()
        else:
            return "\nNot a valid entry\n"
```

Comment: What's in `Definition`???

Comment: Doing a simple test by turning `Definition` to `object` makes it work out OK for me...

Comment: I can corroborate @mgilson 's results.

Comment: Same. Which is why I asked about `Definition`...

Comment: @mgilson why does changing Definition to object make it work? Also I need to inherent some properties from Definition to make the rest of the stuffs work.

Comment: Shouldn't `Lobby.__init` call `Description.__init`? But I don't see how failing to do this could cause this problem.

Comment: Can you show the code that creates multiple `Lobby`s and is getting the same description for all of them?

Comment: @Barmar `Definition.__init__` looks like it's just a stub to keep tests from failing, but I agree that it's unlikely anything in `Definition` is breaking it.

Comment: If you are not using Python 3.x, your base class (Definition)  must inherit from "object" - otherwise all sort of starnge behaviors will show up.

Answer (score 0):

Something in `Definition` is preventing this from working appropriately.

```
class FooClass(object):
    foo = 0
    def __init__(self):
        print("Foo {} before".format(self.__class__.foo))
        self.__class__.foo += 1
        print("Foo {} after".format(self.__class__.foo))
# Works appropriately

>>> x = Foo()
Foo 0 before
Foo 1 after
>>> x = Foo()
Foo 1 before
Foo 2 after
```

However I'd recommend a different way to track this if it's just a binary "seen" variable. Restricting your ability to create multiple `Lobby` objects may mess you up in the future. Strongly consider creating a dictionary that houses all your objects, with a `visit` method that runs the logic your `__init__` is doing now, and sets a flag that makes a following visit do something different.

```
class SomeRoom(Room):
    # where Room is some superclass like Definition is now
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(args)  # or however
        self.__visited = False

    @property
    def visited(self):
        return self.__visited

    def visit(self):
        if self.visited:
            print("Welcome back")
        else:
            print("Welcome!")
        self.__visited = True
```